# Get a while loop into a Code Igniter dropdown array

Tags: php, codeigniter, while-loop, pyrocms

I'm trying to add a set of dummy options to my dropdown to make some jQuery code work. The problem is that although the loop is working I can't figure out how to set the drop down to loop though and get all 50 dummy values it just returns the first one. I know this is like beginner PHP stuff but loops and arrays seem to always be confusing to me.

```
$dummy_value = array('UNASSIGNED');
while ($i <= 50)
{
    $dummy_value = "''=> 'null'";
    $i++;
}

echo form_dropdown('employee_manager',array('null'  => 'Please Select A Manager', $dummy_value)); ?>
```

Ideally I want the `form_dropdown` to contain 50 of `''=> null` vaules. In theory we could add the whole array including the first option to the loop or a variable (I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dummy_value [] = "''=> 'null'";
```